# Scrubbing part of a version tree in SVN

Tags: svn

Got a project that is under SVN. No branches (as there was only two of us and I left one person in charge). How can I remove reversions from *x* onwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this the easy way or the hard way or the lazy-bones way:

- **Easy Way**: Use the `svn merge` command to restore the build to the previous version. This is fast and quick, and you don't have to take the repository down. However, all the old history is still there.
- **Hard Way**: You need to take the repository down, then do the following:

  - Dump the repository using `svnadmin dump`. You can use the `r$first:$last` to specify the range of revisions you want to dump.
  - Move the current repository to another location.
  - Recreate the repository using the `svnadmin load` command.
  - Restart the repository again. Now, you are missing all the bad revisions you wanted to remove.
- **The Lazy-bones Way**: Wait until Subversion 1.8 comes out with the `svn obliterate` command.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not right click and "update to revision"? and you can roll it back until before the other person started making changes, then resubmit it and it will be back at that version.
I'm not sure you can actually delete all the revision from a certain date?

Comment: Just would like to delete all this chaps code (as it is c**p) to ensure that it will not come back in the future to bit us!

Comment: know that feeling.. am not sure then! But let me know if you find out!